# Static data or Application Object or Cache in MVC apps

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, caching, static-data

I am building a website using MVC4. I have a set of objects, which are almost static by nature. Should I opt for Application object or Static data or Cache?

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of Cache is expiration if there are changes. It's much harder to update a static variable or Application. You basically have to recycle the app pool.

I would say Application is left over for backward compatibility with older asp based apps

Comment: I don't think you need to recycle in order to update as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594(v=vs.100).aspx - concurrency section.  

and cache requires additional checks for availability.

Comment: Yes you can build a feature to refresh it, but Cache comes with a life cycle built in.